# comparing between two timestamp

Tags: php, laravel

So I want to compare between two timestamps in one condition to make an active button every 2 hours after each use

This part is in my Home.Blade.Php

(cDelay_Vote)->this is a timestamp that i get from my database

```
@foreach($data as $per)
@if ( date('Y-m-d H:i:s')->greaterThanOrEqualTo(strtotime($per->cDelay_Vote,'+2 hours')))
 <form action="{{ route('home')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{csrf_field()}}
 active Button
</form>
@else
 inactive Button
@endif
@endforeach
```

This is where i get $data from HomeController.php

```
public function index()
    {
        $users = Auth::user()->cUid;
        $data = DB::table('personnages')
            ->join('comptes', 'comptes.cUid', '=','personnages.pUniqueID')
            ->where('pUniqueID','=' , $users)
            ->paginate(1);
        return view('home', compact('data'));
    }
```

Comment: bad idea use `@` symbol to supress errors,i'm about to downvote your question if you don't wirte your full code and your two dates or an example which help us to help you

Comment: @Fernando Urban it's just the part that's causing me a problem i cant use the code and the @ symbol it's in the Laravel framework code i'm not using it to supress errors

Comment: @FernandoUrban using the `@` symbol in a `.blade.php` file is not error suppression; that's how you use directives (`@if`, `@foreach`, `@php`, etc). Please familiarize yourself with Laravel and Blade before making assumptions.

Comment: @BERL1 You can use `Carbon` for this btw, as it's built into Laravel, something like `\Carbon\Carbon::now() >= $per->cDelay_vote`, but you need to make sure that both are Carbon instances. Can you show where `$per->cDelay_Vote` comes from?

Comment: @TimLewis it's his problem, i think, if he want to use `@` symbol for any reason, just asking for the full ode or examples what is trying to do, his code it's very relative

Comment: @FernandoUrban It's really not. The code above is perfectly valid `.blade.php` templating code. The code is an acceptable example of what they're trying to do, but doesn't specify what `$per->cDelay_Vote` is, or what the exact error is. It needs a bit more information, but **the issue is not related to the `@` symbol usage.** Read https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade, it shows multiple instances of `@{whatever}` directives.

Comment: Please i need an answer, or another way to comparing actual timestamp, with the timestamp from my database ! please

Comment: I'd recommend reading up on Carbon: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ . It provides a whole host of commands for date/time manipulation and comparison

Comment: Also, if `cDelay_Vote` is a DateTime column in your database, you can tell [Eloquent that it's a date field](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators), and it will automatically cast it to a Carbon instance.

Comment: @aynber That's of course assuming they have a model and aren't using the `DB` facade to do this query. I got crickets when I asked where `$per->cDelay_Vote` comes from (well, not crickets, but an edit that says "It comes from the database")

Comment: @TimLewis Yes i can show you this :

Im using 
foreach($data as $per) 
       {{$per->cDelay_Vote}}
endforeach

and i get the $data From my HomeController.php

Comment: @BERL1 Show the query that generates `$data`, and please edit code into your question, not in the comments.

Comment: @TimLewis done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use timestamp in database you can do like this

```
@if (date('U') - $per->cDelay_Vote > 60*60*2)
@endif
```

if another field type then

```
@if (date('U') - strtotime($per->cDelay_Vote) > 60*60*2)
@endif
```